# How to deploy a nuxt.js project with Tailwindcss 2.0 on vercel zeit

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vercel, autoprefixer

I'm trying to upload a basic nuxt.js project with tailwind.css 2.0.
I used :

```
yarn add --dev tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

to install tailwindcss 2.0

First I was using npm then yarn but on deployment tailwindcss 2.0 doesn't work.
On local it works great.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get any errors? Are the styles not being applied?

Comment: i got this: 
https://play.tailwindcss.com/qY8AmsoeFW
I know i have to add tailwind/forms it was just to show you what i get.

On local it works

Comment: Is there something wrong with what you linked? Could you explain what were you expecting there?

Comment: Some input are invisible, it should look like this:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/yNUiF1YY8J?file=config

Not this: 

play.tailwindcss.com/qY8AmsoeFW

Comment: Is the problem that `require('@tailwindcss/forms')` is not being used?

Comment: Yes. Can you try to deploy a simple nuxt project with tailwindcss 2.0 to see if it's good for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really tell without more details, but if you are encountering difficulties in production but not in development for a tailwindcss project - the first thing to check is whether you are using dynamic class names (for example, `text-${color}-500`). These [will be purged](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#purgecss-options) in production unless you add them to the allowlist.

**UPDATE**

Having taken a look at the repo you have provided, it looks like the issue is that Tailwind generates CSS targeting `[type='text']` but this is purged by `html-minifier` in the generated HTML of your Nuxt app (see [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8288)). You can turn off this behaviour with this code in your `nuxt.config`:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    html: {
      minify: {
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        processConditionalComments: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        // this is the only line we're changing from defaults
        // but we have to include all as they aren't merged
        removeRedundantAttributes: false,
        trimCustomFragments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No i'm not.
I just want this example to work on vercel:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/qY8AmsoeFW

It's a really a basic nuxt project. I create the project, add tailwind 2.0: It works on local but not on vercel.

Comment: PurgeCSS is enabled by default, if you are using tailwindcss. You can turn it off by following the instructions in the link in my answer above.